# Beginner Javascript course - recommended books

Tags: resource-request, javascript, html, css

I was asked to teach Javascript to total beginners. Since it would most likely be free of charge, I would rather not spend time making my own slides and material. I would follow a book or some other existing material, draw things on whiteboard for further clarification, do simple quizzes, and focus on helping students actually code stuff.

Ideally this book or material would:

- Cover Javascript but also HTML and CSS basics
- Have some quizzes
- Be interesting for beginners
- Be more modern JS oriented
- Also touch upon NodeJS with some command line and server development

Answer (score 5):

A great resource to learn JavaScript is Eloquent JavaScript by Marijn Haverbeke: https://eloquentjavascript.net/.

You can download the pdf for free, or you can read it online, and this is probably a better choice since you can take advantage of the code sandbox.

It is definitely suitable for beginners but a wide range of topics is covered, included Node.js (chapter 20). However, with regards to your requests, HTML and CSS are introduced but you will probably need supplementary material about them.

Comment: I see that doesn't have quizzes, but I could easily do those myself based on the book content.

Answer (score 0):

a book that i recommend for you is *Head First JavaScript Programming* at this link the description is found [the book description](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-javascript/9781449340124/)
but if you need to make the lecture more interesting I would recommend that you use this site for learning JavaScript which is [code academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn) the course is named introduction to JavaScript this site provides an introductory course to JavaScript and give instant feedback to the student of what is right and wrong and i use it in my lectures as an introductory course in introduction to programming the web

Comment: Doesn't the Code Academy require paid subscription?