# What is a good textbook for teaching Web Programming?

Tags: programming, web-development

Is there any textbook you would recommend as appropriate for preparing a Web Programming college course? I would prefer a book that comes with sets of exercises, practice, code examples, etc. Students are university level expected to have programming knowledge and to know about Internet. No knowledge of particular Internet technologies is required. Do you have any good practices you can share about Web Programming teaching?

Comment: Can you improve the question by telling us: What age, What prier knowledge (can students program in another language?, do students know `HTML` and/or `CSS`?, do students know the difference between a web-browser, internet, web, …?

Comment: Do you need a _textbook_ per se? I've taught web programming (I assume you mean basically HTML5: HTML/CSS/vanilla JS) for years but I've never used a book for it. Some colleges require(?) courses to be based on textbooks, so more context/motivation for why you need a textbook as opposed to any other resources would be nice. Are there particular skills you are hoping to teach? Any particular emphasis you want to place on apps, sites or games? Front-end web development is a broad topic. If you are open to using libraries and frameworks (React, Vue, p5, three.js etc), the scope blows up.

Comment: Related: [Beginner Javascript course - recommended books](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5151/beginner-javascript-course-recommended-books)

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite vague in terms of what you're asking for. I don't know the age of the students, their prior knowledge or what exactly you want to teach them other that "Web Programming" which could mean a lot of things.

Assuming it is an introductory HTML/CSS/JS course you're teaching, I also teach this kind of course to students of various ages and abilities. Two resources I've found useful when doing this are the projects on Raspberry Pi [https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/?software[]=html-css-javascript](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/?software%5B%5D=html-css-javascript) and the content and exercises on W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/.

This unit on code.org might also be helpful although I have not used it myself https://studio.code.org/s/csd2-2021

I hope you find those suggestions useful. I don't teach practical web related courses other than introductory HTML/CSS so unfortunately I can't make suggestions on any other content you might be teaching.